# Rails link_to controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a rails CRUD application for practice. Here is the contents of my routes.rb:

```
get ‘/events’ => ‘events#index’
post ‘/events’ => ‘events#create’
get ‘/events/new’ => ‘events#new’, as: :’new_event’
get ‘/events/:id/edit’ => ‘events#edit’, as: :’edit_event’
get ‘/events/:id’ => ‘events#show’, as: :’event’
patch ‘/events/:id’ => ‘events#update’
put ‘/events/:id’ => ‘events#update’  
delete ‘/events/:id’ => ‘events#destroy’
```

My new event page currently employs a Create button, see code for new.html.erb below:

```
  <h1>New Event</h1>
  <%= link_to “Back”,”/events” %><br><br>
   <table border=”1”>
    <tr>
     <th>Event</th>
     <th>Venue</th>
     <th>Start Time</th>
     <th>End Time</th>
     <th>Description</th>
   </tr>
<%= form_for(@event) do |t| %> 
  <tr>
    <td><%= t.text_field :event %></td>
    <td><%= t.text_field :venue%></td>
    <td><%= t.date_field :start_date%></td>
    <td><%= t.date_field :end_date%></td>
    <td><%= t.text_area :description%></td>
     <td><%= f.submit “Create” %><br><br></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I want to replace the Create button with a Create link while still maintaining the rest of the code in new.html.erb

I can't seem to figure out how to create a link_to that submits the data collected from the text boxes on the page. I am able to statically submit information using the below code:

```
<%= link_to 'Create', events_path(:event => "Genesis", :venue => "Blossom", :start_date => "2017-01-01", :end_date => "2017-01-02", :description => "2017 Tour") :method => :post %>
```

Comment: Can I first ask why do you need a link and not a button? If you're submitting the form using HTML, anybody would expect to see a button. Also, why do you split the routes on the routes.rb file rather than using "resources :events" to automatically generate the paths?

Comment: I am aware that I can use the resources :events to generate all of my CRUD routes. I manually entered them so as to understand how they worked as this was a learning activity.

Comment: I used the following Delete link_to code on another html.erb page and wanted all of my CRUD controls to be consistent.                                                                                                               <%= link_to ‘Delete’, event_path(t), method: :delete, data: { confirm: ‘Are you sure?’ } %>

Comment: What is that chunk of code you pasted? Are you using jQuery in your app?

Comment: I am not using jQuery, the inspiration to use a link_to for my controller actions came directly from the official Ruby on Rails website under their "Getting Started" section, the example used a link_to for the Delete function. [link] (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#deleting-articles)

Comment: Oh I see where your confusion is coming from. You can use a link for a delete action because you don't need to pass parameters collected from a form, like you do when creating an object. The only thing you need to delete an object, is its ID, and that's what you are sending in event_path(t). Believe me that in the 99.99% of the cases, you'll find buttons to submit forms, is the natural way to do it and there's no reason to take a different way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Jquery :

```
$(document).on("click", "#your_link", function(){
   $("#form").submit();
});
```